# Scraping with scrapy in paginated links using start url not working

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I tried to scrap a website which has paginated links so i did this

```
import scrapy

class SummymartSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'dummymart'
    allowed_domains = ['www.dummrmart.com/product']
    start_urls = ['https://www.dummymart.net/product/auto-parts--118?page%s'% page for page in range(1,20)]
```

It worked!! with the single url it works but when i try to do this:

```
  import scrapy
    class DummymartSpider(scrapy.Spider):
        name = 'dummymart'
        allowed_domains = ['www.dummymart.com/product']
        start_urls = ['https://www.dummymart.net/product/auto-parts--118?page%s',
        'https://www.dummymart.net/product/accessories-tools--112?id=1316264860?page%s'% page for page in range(1,20)]
```

It does not work, how do I implement same logic but for multiple URLs? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do it is by using the `start_requests()` method of `scrapy.Spider` instead of using `start_urls` attribute. [You can see more here](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#scrapy.spiders.Spider.start_requests)

```
import scrapy

class DummymartSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'dummymart'
    allowed_domains = ['dummymart.com']

    def start_requests(self):
        for page in range(1,20):
            yield scrapy.Request(
                url='https://www.dummymart.net/product/auto-parts--118?page%s' % page,
                callback=self.parse,
            )
            yield scrapy.Request(
                url='https://www.dummymart.net/product/accessories-tools--112?id=1316264860?page%s' % page,
                callback=self.parse,
            )
```

If you want to keep using the `start_urls` attribute, you can try something like this (I haven't tested it):

`start_urls = ['https://www.dummymart.net/product/auto-parts--118?page%s' % page for page in range(1,20)] + ['https://www.dummymart.net/product/accessories-tools--112?id=1316264860?page%s'% page for page in range(1,20)]`

Also note that in the `allowed_domains` attribute you only need to specify the domain. [See here](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#scrapy.spiders.Spider.allowed_domains).

Comment: the latter one works. thanks. i will check the first one and update you

Comment: and what if the range is unknown cause it is different for each link?

Comment: also i have those list of links in a csv file, how to include it cause it will take a long time manually entering it, thanks

Comment: If the range is unknown, you can begin with the first page of each urls, and then iterate trough pages by parsing the next page url on the current page.
example:


`next_url = response.css('#next_url::attr(href)').extract_first()
return scrapy.Request(url=next_url, callback=self.parse)`

Comment: If you want to parse urls from a csv file, you can use the `start_requests()` method as shown in my first answer, and read the csv file [like so](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html)

Comment: i couldn't get through the documentation. Can you help me with the syntax where do i put it? my csv file contents demo:'https://www.dummymart.net/product/valve-parts--12209?id=2080591441'
'https://www.dummymart.net/product/used-clothes--1099?page=2'
'https://www.dummymart.net/product/abrasives--13065?id=1209654185'